# Render an url of type ?x=1&y=2 with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Im trying to print, using a xslt sheet a url but im having problems with the chars = and &:

This is the url that i want to render:

```
<a href="whatever.aspx?x=1&y=2">whatever</a>
```

Im getting that "=" is an unexpected token.

How should i have to put the = and the & in a xslt sheet?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Jose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your ampersand, as that is the symbol used to denote the start of an entity:

```
<a href="whatever.aspc?x=1&amp;y=2">whatever</a>
```